# JSON parser java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask

im getting this error, trying to build a JSON parser with a ListView.
I tried this code with another JSON source and it works but with this link crashes:
http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson

I´d love some help :D

Error:

```
05-21 20:53:32.871 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake     W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake    W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err:     at    com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake.MainActivity.ParseJSON(MainActivity.java:102)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake  W/System.err:     at   com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:19)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake  W/System.err:     at  com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake.MainActivity$GetTerremotos.doInBackground(Mai nActivity.java:70)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake  W/System.err:     at  com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake.MainActivity$GetTerremotos.doInBackground(Mai nActivity.java:44)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake  W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake  W/System.err:     at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
05-21 20:53:32.872 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_FEATURES = "features";
private static final String TAG_PROPERTIES = "properties";
private static final String TAG_LUGAR = "lugar";
private static final String TAG_MAGNITUD = "magnitud";
private static final String TAG_HORA = "hora";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetTerremotos().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class GetTerremotos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> terremotostList;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        WebRequest webreq = new WebRequest();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = webreq.makeWebServiceCall(url, WebRequest.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        terremotostList = ParseJSON(jsonStr);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, terremotostList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_LUGAR, TAG_MAGNITUD,
                TAG_HORA}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ParseJSON(String json) {
    if (json != null) {
        try {
            // Hashmap for ListView
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray terremotos = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FEATURES);

            // looping through All HeartQuakes
            for (int i = 0; i < terremotos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = terremotos.getJSONObject(i);




                // Properties node is JSON Object
                JSONObject properties = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PROPERTIES);
                String lugar = properties.getString(TAG_LUGAR);
                String magnitud = properties.getString(TAG_MAGNITUD);
                String hora = properties.getString(TAG_HORA);

                // tmp hashmap for single hq
                HashMap<String, String> oterremoto = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                oterremoto.put(TAG_LUGAR, lugar);
                oterremoto.put(TAG_MAGNITUD, magnitud);
                oterremoto.put(TAG_HORA, hora);


                // adding student to hq list
                studentList.add(oterremoto);
            }
            return studentList;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

WebRequest class:

```
public class WebRequest {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

//Constructor with no parameter
public WebRequest() {

}

/**
 * Making web service call
 *
 * @url - url to make request
 * @requestmethod - http request method
 */
public String makeWebServiceCall(String url, int requestmethod) {
    return this.makeWebServiceCall(url, requestmethod, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 *
 * @url - url to make request
 * @requestmethod - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 */
public String makeWebServiceCall(String urladdress, int requestmethod,
                                 HashMap<String, String> params) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urladdress);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        if (requestmethod == POST) {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } else if (requestmethod == GET) {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }

        if (params != null) {
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            writer.write(result.toString());

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

}

Comment: `ParseJSON(jsonStr)` in `terremotostList = ParseJSON(jsonStr)` may be returning null. Can you log your JSON string at the start of `ParseJSON(jsonStr)` to ensure the `JSON` was downloaded correctly?

Comment: I think the problem is what you said, but im a newbie and i dont know how to check if the JSON string was downloaded.

Comment: Well @R. Kirill did a great job pinpointing the issue but you could benefit from learning how to debug server responses so do this: Before `if (json != null)` try `Log.v("JSON Response", json)`, then check the logcat to see if you get response the link you provided gives.

Comment: At the logcat i can check that i hace an error here:    `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);`

Comment: Actually I took a second look and you're already logging your JSON response. It's this statement `Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);` So search for it on your logcat. If you're not getting a response, you should be getting an exception in the `ParseJSON` method & it should be producing a stacktrace. Post the result from that stacktrace.

Comment: maybe u mean if im getting this: `05-21 20:53:32.871 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake D/Response:: > 
05-21 20:53:32.871 2509-2606/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of    `

Comment: Yeah so you're getting something and then an exception gets thrown, edit your post with everything from the stacktrace, that is the `W/System' tag.

Comment: i hope that is what u were asking for :)

Comment: Yeah that's it. Your JSON is definitely empty so there is an issue with the request, the URL is good, did you add internet permissions in the manifest? What is the WebRequest class? I can't seem to find documentation on it.

Comment: i add the WebRequest class, and i have the permissions in the manifest :D

Comment: Try this, in the WebRequest class towards the bottom where you have `response="";` change it to `response="debug";`. Then let me know if when you run it, right above first `W/System.err`, you see `Response > debug`.

Comment: `05-21 23:07:41.592 2728-2753/com.ikeres.app.professorearthquake D/Response:: > debug` there is the message

Comment: Okay this statement `if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)` is failing, either remove the condition or see why it is failing.

Comment: if i remove the condition it dies

Comment: The comment thread is getting a bit long, how about you post the whole project in github or pastebin so I can look at all of it there?

Comment: https://github.com/ikergravalos/Professor-EarthQuake
Here is my repository, if u wanna try it :D and thx u so much m8

Comment: I'll check it out and comment back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. Remove the following lines from the `WebRequest` class:

```
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

add the following after `conn.setRequestMethod("GET");`:

```
conn.connect();
```

Now you get `JSON` out of the `API`. After that your app would not display anything. That's because your tags are all in spanish and the `API` is in english so change:

```
private static final String TAG_LUGAR = "lugar";
private static final String TAG_MAGNITUD = "magnitud";
private static final String TAG_HORA = "hora";
```

to:

```
private static final String TAG_LUGAR = "place";
private static final String TAG_MAGNITUD = "mag";
private static final String TAG_HORA = "time";
```

It works after these changes.

Comment: You are right man, I really love you, thanks very much for ur help!!

Comment: No problem at all, glad I could help, sorry it took a while. Just mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for fields existence when parsing your json. Your code fails at this line:

```
String lugar = properties.getString(TAG_LUGAR);
```

because there is no such field `lugar` in the returned json. So this line throws an exception, which is catched with this code:

```
catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

and returns `NULL`. Then, you are creating an adapter and passing a null object:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, terremotostList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_LUGAR, TAG_MAGNITUD,
            TAG_HORA}, new int[]{R.id.name,
            R.id.email, R.id.mobile});
```

(`terremotostList` is null)

and finally your adapter fails trying to access `getCount` method of your list, which is null.

How to solve this problem? You should either check for field existence before getting its value:

```
String lugar = properties.has(TAG_LUGAR) ? properties.getString(TAG_LUGAR) : null;
```

or just use `optString` method, which doesn't throw an exception if field doesn't exist:

```
String lugar = properties.optString(TAG_LUGAR);
```

Comment: Thx, I tried this but it still crash, i tried to parse another url and it works, im so confused right now

Comment: did you try to replace with optString the other string fields as well (magnitud and hora) ?

Comment: Also Daniel mentioned above that you have to ensure that you receive the json from the server and it is not empty

Comment: Yes, i think the json in not being downloaded